# React component return empty object when server side rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I am getting a weird behaviour when I try to implement server side rendering on a react app.

```
...
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a
class/function (for composite components) but got: object. 
You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
...
```

I realised that there is a general issue with render files with JSX extension. Here is what my code looks like.

*./server/server.js*

```js
app.use('/*', (req, res, next) => {
  const context = {};
  const app = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <App />
  );

  console.log(app)

  fs.readFile(path.resolve('./build/index.html'), 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).send("Some Error")
    }

    return res.send(
      data.replace(
        '<div id="root"></div>',
        `<div id="root">${app}</div>`
      )
    )
  })
})
```

*./server/index.js*

```js
require("ignore-styles")

require("@babel/register")({
    ignore: [/(node_module)/],
    presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
})

require('./server')
```

*./src/App.jsx*

```js
import './App.scss';
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='app'>
     <p>Sample</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

*./src/index.js*

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.scss';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.hydrate(
  <Router>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

And the error occurs when in `../server/server.js:17:30` which is when `ReactDOMServer.renderToString` is called. The issue is that the component are seen as an empty object after they are imported. I have a feeling it is an issue with babel but I am not sure.

Comment: Is the react app as a string getting sent correctly to the browser? Also, what do you call in the browser to render the react app from a string to an app? (Do you call `ReactDOM.hydrate(...)`?)

Comment: they are not getting sent to the browser at all. They fail at `ReactDOMServer.renderToString`  and yes I called ReactDOM.hydrate.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem recently with a very similar setup. During SSR the components which had `.js` extension returned the expected React components, while the `.jsx` files returned `{}`.

In my case I changed the imports from

```
import App from './components/App'
```

to

```
import App from './components/App.jsx'
```

and it fixed the issue. After this modification both the server and client side render returns the expected components.